# Dynamically determine which button of a particular class has been clicked with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A demo of my dilemma [here](https://jsfiddle.net/naught0k/fLnm24we/22/)

Let's say I have the following html:

```
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <body>
    <div class="main" id="thingSection">
      <h1>
        Test Header
      </h1>
      <button class="btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-windows"></i> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-toggle-off"></i> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-apple"></i></button>
      <div class="content" id="content1">
        Some content
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="main" id="thingSection1">
      <h1>
        Another Test
      </h1>
      <button class="btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-windows"></i> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-toggle-off"></i> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-apple"></i></button>
      <div class="content" id="content2">
        Some content
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="main" id="thingSection2">
      <h1>
        Another test, you say?
      </h1>
      <button class="btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-windows"></i> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-toggle-off"></i> <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-apple"></i></button>
      <div class="content" id="content3">
        Some content
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I am using the following jquery to change the `toggle` icon from FontAwesome from off to on:

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn-icon').click(function() {
    if ($(this).find($(".fa")).hasClass('fa-toggle-off')) {
      $("i.fa-toggle-off").toggleClass('fa-toggle-on');
    } else {
      $("i.fa-toggle-on").toggleClass('fa-toggle-off');
    }
  });
});
```

When I click the button to toggle the icon, it works as expected, i.e. it changes *all* of the buttons on the page. However, I would like to dynamically determine *which* button has been pressed, and then change the content of a child `div` based on the position of the switch.

I want to avoid hardcoding id's for each button to avoid a ton of `if/else` statements in the script that must be updated each time I, say, add a new button or a new section. That is to say, I want to dynamically detect which button has been pressed, and affect only that button and its children.

I've noticed that `console.log(this)` yields only the HTML for the particular button that has been pressed, not all of the buttons.

I'm a novice with jquery. I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem yet, and I feel like there *has* to be a way to do this dynamically without hardcoding IDs.

---

**EDIT**: I've accomplished (partially) what I want to do with the following code:

```
$(function() {

    $('.btn-icon').click(function() {
        var t = $(this).find('.is-toggle');

        if (t.hasClass('fa-toggle-off')) {
            t.addClass('fa-toggle-on');
            t.removeClass('fa-toggle-off');
        }
        else {

            t.addClass('fa-toggle-off');
            t.removeClass('fa-toggle-on');
        }
    });

});
```

Looks like I just didn't understand what exactly `$(this)` was (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `$(this)` that selects the element that triggered the event. From there you can select down to the div you want.

EDIT: Here is how that might look in code, I pulled this from your fiddle and edited it

```
$(function() {
  $('.btn-icon').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.fa-toggle-off, .fa-toggle-on').toggleClass('fa-toggle-on fa-toggle-off');
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not 100% sure what exactly you mean or how it would look in code. I've added a class to the icon I want toggled called `is-toggle` (creative I know). So now I should be able to more easily determine which `<i>` is the one I want to change. Now I have `var toggle = $(this).find($('.is-toggle'));` but that's not yielding great results

Comment: thank you for that! I was finally able to accomplish literally everything I wanted to do (with animations to boot!).